# When crowds chant “¡Kiricocho!” what are they saying?

Tags: traducción, definiciones, argentina, deportes

**When crowds chant “¡Kiricocho!” what are they saying?**

I recently came upon the following:

> Kiricocho es la palabra más usada en el ambiente futbolero ...

If you visit [**the page on which I found it,**](https://www.taringa.net/posts/noticias/2052402/Kiricocho-mufada.html) you'll see that it is a sports term of sorts that is used:

> ... cada vez que un equipo tiene una situación en contra de su arco.

I don't watch a lot of organized sports so my terminology in that arena is a bit limited.  What is a good layman's definition of this and what’s the best English equivalent of it?

---

**Cuando los multitudes cantan “¡Kiricocho!” ¿qué dicen?**

Recientemente me topé con el siguiente:

> Kiricocho es la palabra más usada en el ambiente futbolero ...

Si visitas la página en el que lo encontré, verás que es un término deportivo que se usa:

> ... cada vez que un equipo tiene una situación en contra de su arco.

No veo muchos deportes organizados así que mi terminología en esa arena puede limitarse.  ¿Qué es una buena definición de esta palabra para entendernos?  ¿Qué es el mejor traducción de ella en iglés?

Comment: El texto que enlazas usa muchas expresiones argentinas; si no estás acostumbrada a su vocabulario, es normal que tengas dificultades para comprenderlo. Por lo que entiendo en él, un *mufa* es lo que generalmente llamamos un *gafe*; es decir, una persona que supuestamente trae mala suerte. Por eso los aficionados nombrarían a Kiricocho, quien, según la página, era gafe. Sería parecido a nombrar a Macbeth entre las gentes del teatro en Inglaterra.

Comment: Me gusta mucho tu comentario, @Gorpik.  Si quieres ponerla en la forma de una respuesta, daría la marca verde.

Comment: De acuerdo, voy a intentarlo.

Answer (score 2):

El texto que enlazas está lleno de expresiones porteñas, el habla propia de Buenos Aires y sus alrededores. Entre ellas, *mufa*, que equivale a lo que en otros lugares llamaríamos *gafe*; una persona que supuestamente trae mala suerte.

Kiricocho era un *mufa*. Entre los supersticiosos, el poder de los gafes es tan grande que no es necesario que estén presentes; con tan solo nombrarlos dan mala suerte. Por eso los aficionados nombran al *mufa* Kiricocho cuando quieren dar mala suerte al delantero contrario que está a punto de tirar un penalty.

Otros colectivos tienen supersticiones similares. Por ejemplo, entre las gentes del teatro británicas, la tragedia de Shakespeare *Macbeth* da mala suerte. Por ello los supersticiosos se refieren a ella como *[la obra escocesa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scottish_Play)*, para evitar nombrarla.

Answer (score 1):

**English:**

This was originally going to be part of the question, but since it at least hints at a possible meaning for this word, I thought it would be best to add it as an answer until a native speaker or someone in the know gets a chance to respond.  My answer (or, more truthfully, line of investigation) follows:

For the record, I did what I could to find a good translation of this (kiricocho), but nothing solid has really materialized thus far.

Though the word does not come up in a Google Ngram search, I was able to find 4,400 Google pages for the word.

Additional clues come from the page itself where, immediately after the word “kiricocho,” in parentheses, is another word ([**mufada**](https://termbank.com/en/spanish-english/mufada)) that I did not find listed in the dictionaries I took a look at — [**Tureng,**](https://termbank.com/en/spanish-english/mufada) [**RAE,**](http://dle.rae.es/) [**WordReference,**](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/mufada) and others.  That said, I did find this Collins entry via Reverso:

## [estar mufado](http://context.reverso.net/translation/spanish-english/mufado)

A cursory scan of the pages with a little help from Chrome translation seems to indicate that this word “mufado/-a” often means “muffled.”  However, the first instance of "kiricocho" I find is from a [**Facebook account**](https://www.google.com/search?q=kiricocho&lr=lang_es&as_qdr=all&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3Alang_1es%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A2000%2Ccd_max%3A2001&tbm=) for what appears to be a clothing brand in Argentina whose slogan is “sacate la mufa” which seems to carry a meaning of “get the jinx.”

Cobbling these hints and clues together, to include [**this one from PONS**](https://en.pons.com/translate/spanish-english/mufarse) and [**these from Tureng**](https://termbank.com/en/spanish-english/mufa), I’m going to go out on a limb here and say that it would appear that “¡Kiricocho!” is something a crowd shouts when it wants the other team to miss its shot.  Despite the stories of its origin that you’ll find, I have to wonder if it might not be some sort of substitution.  For example, if the Nike brand is so associated with the phrase “Just Do It,” just the word “Nike” could, conceivably, be used as a stand-in for the phrase “Just Do It”. Either way, chanting “¡Kiricocho!” appears to be equivalent to something like “Jinx!” in English or whatever it is people shout out for such things nowadays.

The use of this word may not be known in all parts of the Spanish-speaking world, but it obviously must be used in Argentina and it is likely that it is known throughout at least the Southern Cone region due to the intrarregionality of competition there must be for a popular sport like soccer.

**Español:**

Esta respuesta iba a ser parte de mi pregunta, pero dado que, al menos, apunte a un significado posible de esta palabra, pensé que sería mejor añadirla como una respuesta hasta que un hispanohablante nativo, o alguien que sabe, tiene la oportunidad de responder.  Mi respuesta (o, más exactamente, línea de investigación) sigue:

Para que conste, hice lo que podría para encontrar una buena traducción de esta palabra (kiricocho), pero realmente nada sólido ha materializado todavía.

Aunque la palabra “kiricocho” no surge en una búsqueda de los Ngrams de Google, puede encontrarse en 4,400 páginas de Google.

Pistas adicionales viene de la página en sí misma donde, inmediatamente después de la palabra “kiricocho”, hay otra palabra ([**mufada**](https://termbank.com/en/spanish-english/mufada)) que no encontré listada en los diccionarios a los que eché un vistazo — [**Tureng,**](https://termbank.com/en/spanish-english/mufada) [**RAE,**](http://dle.rae.es/) [**WordReference,**](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/mufada) y otros.  Dicho eso, he encontrado este artículo de Collins via Reverso:

## [estar mufado](http://context.reverso.net/translation/spanish-english/mufado)

Una inspección rápido de las páginas con un poco de ayuda del traductor de Chrome parece indicar que esta palabra “mufado/-a” a menudo significa “muffled.”  Sin embargo, la primera instancia de "kiricocho" que encuentro es de una cuenta de Facebook para lo que aparece ser una marca de ropa en Argentina cuyo lema es “sacate la mufa” que parece lleva un significado de “get the jinx.”

Improvisando estos indicios y pistas, incluso [**ésto de PONS**](https://en.pons.com/translate/spanish-english/mufarse) y [**éstos de Tureng**](https://termbank.com/en/spanish-english/mufa), voy a ir por las ramas aquí y decir que parecería que “¡Kiricocho!” es algo que una multitud grita cuando quiere que el otro equipo falle el tiro.  A pesar de las historias de su origen que encontrarás, tengo que preguntarme si puede que no sea algún tipo de sustitución.  Por ejemplo, si la marca Nike es tan íntimamente vinculada con la frase “Sólo hazlo”, sólo la palabra “Nike” podría, concebiblemente, servir como sustituta de la frase “Sólo hazlo”.  De cualquier manera, cantando “¡Kiricocho!” parece ser equivalente a algo como “¡Jinx!” en inglés o lo que sea que la gente grite para esas cosas hoy en día.

Es posible que el uso de esta palabra puede no ser conocido en todas partes del mundo hispanohablante, pero obviamente los argentinos utilizársela, y es probable que es conocida por lo menos en la región del Cono Sur debido al carácter interregional de la competencia debe haber para un deporte popular como fútbol.

Comment: Lisa, I have a suggestion.  Rather than drafting your question first in English, and then translating it to Spanish, how about trying the other way around?  1. First, jot down an outline of the logical thread of what you want to write.  That can be in English if you want.  No full sentences, please, at this stage.  2. Now, write your outline again but with Spanish terms.  3. Add to this skeleton some key vocabulary items that you'll want to have available to you when you start writing.  4. Now, start writing, directly in Spanish.  Use simple sentence structures. Think Hemingway! ...

Comment: 5. Now, finally, you get to write in English.  It's okay if the English version doesn't come out as an exact translation of the Spanish. // The beauty of this approach is that it allows you to *think in Spanish.*

Comment: @aparente001 I don't know why you so very often feel a need to critique my posts in any way you can when I don't see you doing that to others.  In fact, I don't even see you enforcing the rule about posting in both English and Spanish with others, yet you continue to vaguely critique my contributions.  The comments you made here have nothing to do with the content of this post.  A better place for comments such as yours would be in a Community Wiki or in the Help section.  For the record, though, I would really appreciate it if you stopped commenting on my posts.  I don't find them helpful.

Comment: Lisa - I edit lots and lots of posts.  I hope it's reassuring to you to know that you aren't the only one.  // As I wrote on the other page just now, I will refrain from editing, polishing, or suggesting improvements to *your* posts, now that I know that it made you uncomfortable (which I was not aware of before, and which was not my intention). // The suggestion I made here about your process was truly intended in a constructive way.  I admire your hard work and dedication with your language study, and was trying, in what seems to have been a clumsy way, to help. // Would you like me...

Comment: ... to remove the two comments I posted here? // The suggested procedure I outlined here wouldn't be relevant for most people, because most people post in either Spanish or English but not both, as you generally do. // "I don't even see you enforcing the rule about posting in both English and Spanish with others" - I'm completely lost.  Do we have such a rule?  Where is it posted?  I wasn't aware of it. (I thought the reason you were posting in both languages was as an exercise you were posing for yourself -- and I was impressed with the extra work you did.)